# Full screen textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, android-browser

How can I get a full screen text box using only js, jquery or css ?
Most phones have this thing when the textbox goes full screen and you can see the textbox only.
I looked this up but found some solutions only at app level. I'm doing this at an webpage so not possible to make app changes.

And the textbox is inside a popover and hence changing its width and height won't work.

So is there anyway to achieve this using normal web components ??

Comment: Can you please share some of the code you are currently using, such as the popup code, so the context is more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the HTML5 Fullscreen API, the tutorial I linked works with videos but the same idea can be used for any element I guess. It is experimental but supported on webkit and moz. Heres the link:

[MDN Fullscreen HTML5 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)

As a footnote, I would have added this as a comment but my reputation isnt high enough yet, so just posted here.

Answer (score 0):

are looking for something like [this(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/phutis/kj18znz9/)?

```
<textarea id="fill-screen"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
$('#fill-screen').focus(function(){
    $('#fill-screen').css({'height': window.innerHeight,
                           'width':window.innerWidth});
    })
});
```